# How can i change the hotkey to trigger backslash in in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

i am desperately looking for a way to rebind the backslash symbol on macOS. Preferably something like control + 0. Anything is better than the default keybind. I googled everything that came to my mind related to this matter but I am still lost on how to manage to do it, it looks like this is not as simple as I've thought.

I downloaded karabiner elements but there is no option to define custom keybinds for the backslash symbol.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

### Edit:

I've tried to bind my right command key to left shift + left option in the .json file, but it's not working unfortunately. Did i do something wrong? This is the .json file with my custom command:

```
{
    "global": {
        "check_for_updates_on_startup": true,
        "show_in_menu_bar": true,
        "show_profile_name_in_menu_bar": false
    },
    "profiles": [
        {
            "complex_modifications": {
                "parameters": {
                    "basic.simultaneous_threshold_milliseconds": 50,
                    "basic.to_delayed_action_delay_milliseconds": 500,
                    "basic.to_if_alone_timeout_milliseconds": 1000,
                    "basic.to_if_held_down_threshold_milliseconds": 500,
                    "mouse_motion_to_scroll.speed": 100
                },
                "rules": []
            },
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "description": "Change right command to option+shift.",
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "right_command",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "optional": [
                                            "any"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "right_command",
                                        "modifiers": [
                                            "left_option",
                                            "left_shift"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
            "devices": [
                {
                    "disable_built_in_keyboard_if_exists": false,
                    "fn_function_keys": [],
                    "identifiers": {
                        "is_keyboard": true,
                        "is_pointing_device": false,
                        "product_id": 591,
                        "vendor_id": 1452
                    },
                    "ignore": false,
                    "manipulate_caps_lock_led": true,
                    "simple_modifications": []
                },
                {
                    "disable_built_in_keyboard_if_exists": false,
                    "fn_function_keys": [],
                    "identifiers": {
                        "is_keyboard": true,
                        "is_pointing_device": false,
                        "product_id": 641,
                        "vendor_id": 1452
                    },
                    "ignore": false,
                    "manipulate_caps_lock_led": true,
                    "simple_modifications": []
                }
            ],
            "fn_function_keys": [
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f1"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "display_brightness_decrement"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f2"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "display_brightness_increment"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f3"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "apple_vendor_keyboard_key_code": "mission_control"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f4"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "apple_vendor_keyboard_key_code": "spotlight"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f5"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "dictation"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f6"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "f6"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f7"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "rewind"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f8"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "play_or_pause"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f9"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "fast_forward"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f10"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "mute"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f11"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "volume_decrement"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f12"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "volume_increment"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "name": "Default profile",
            "parameters": {
                "delay_milliseconds_before_open_device": 1000
            },
            "selected": true,
            "simple_modifications": [],
            "virtual_hid_keyboard": {
                "country_code": 0,
                "indicate_sticky_modifier_keys_state": true,
                "mouse_key_xy_scale": 100
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What language is your keyboard? Backslash has its own key on US/UK/International English. I'd guess German from your profile, but it would be nice if you clarified that.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. Yes, German is correct. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Zest, I have rolled back the question so it does not contain your solution as that is not how thing are done here. Please post your solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily put backslash on any main, shift, or option keystroke you want via a custom layout made with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/).

Note also that if you use the layout called German Standard, instead of German, backslash is on Option ß, instead of Option Shift 7.

Answer (score 0):

The found a work around using the .json file:

```
{
    "global": {
        "check_for_updates_on_startup": true,
        "show_in_menu_bar": true,
        "show_profile_name_in_menu_bar": false
    },
    "profiles": [
        {
            "complex_modifications": {
                "parameters": {
                    "basic.simultaneous_threshold_milliseconds": 50,
                    "basic.to_delayed_action_delay_milliseconds": 500,
                    "basic.to_if_alone_timeout_milliseconds": 1000,
                    "basic.to_if_held_down_threshold_milliseconds": 500,
                    "mouse_motion_to_scroll.speed": 100
                },
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "description": "Right command + 7 => Backslash(\\)",
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "hyphen",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "mandatory": [
                                            "right_command"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "7",
                                        "modifiers": [
                                            "left_option",
                                            "left_shift"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "devices": [],
            "fn_function_keys": [
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f1"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "display_brightness_decrement"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f2"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "display_brightness_increment"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f3"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "apple_vendor_keyboard_key_code": "mission_control"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f4"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "apple_vendor_keyboard_key_code": "spotlight"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f5"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "dictation"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f6"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "f6"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f7"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "rewind"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f8"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "play_or_pause"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f9"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "fast_forward"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f10"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "mute"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f11"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "volume_decrement"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "from": {
                        "key_code": "f12"
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "consumer_key_code": "volume_increment"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "name": "Default profile",
            "parameters": {
                "delay_milliseconds_before_open_device": 1000
            },
            "selected": true,
            "simple_modifications": [],
            "virtual_hid_keyboard": {
                "country_code": 0,
                "indicate_sticky_modifier_keys_state": true,
                "mouse_key_xy_scale": 100
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What this does is assigning the backslash symbol to the right command + ß key as it's usual on german windows keyboards.

Comment: All my Info says Windows German has backslash on option/alt ß, which Apple’s German Standard already has.  Why do you think it is “command”?